# How to Copy array of vectors, using = raises error Expression:transposed pointer range

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, copy

I need to copy array of vector passed as reference to constructor/function.

member variable gets the reference to the passed array of vector

while running below code I am getting error Expression: Transposed pointer range

```
#define MAX 1001
Constructor( std::vector< int > (&Adj)[MAX])
{
    (this->Adj[MAX]) = Adj[MAX];
}
```

Comment: Your problem occurs because you're trying to copy a vector that doesn't exist. If it had existed, `Adj[MAX]` would be *one* vector, not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) to copy an array:

```
#include <cstddef>    // size_t
#include <vector>     // std::vector<>
#include <algorithm>  // std::copy();

constexpr size_t max{ 3 };

struct foo {
    std::vector<int> Adj[max];

    foo(std::vector<int> (&values)[max])
    {
        std::copy(std::begin(values), std::end(values), std::begin(Adj));
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> values[max];
    foo f{ values };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really want an *array* of fixed (compile-time) size of `std::vector`, use `std::array`

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>

Constructor (const std::array<std::vector<int>, MAX>& rhs)
{
   this->Adj = rhs;
}
```

and declare `Adj` as

```
std::array<std::vector<int>, MAX> Adj
```